# Даёт ли что-нибудь нового Cygwin по сравнению в Bash, входящего в дистрибутив СКВ Git?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin

Имеет ли смысл устанавливать Cygwin, если на компьютере с Windows уже установлена система контроля версий Git (в котороую входит терминал Baskh)?

Возможно, вопрос и не корректен, но потому я его и задаю, чтобы во всём разобраться. На данный момент мне известно, консоль, поставляемая с системой контроля версий Git, работает в какой-то оболочке, внутри которой доступны некоторые Linux-команды, например OpenSSH.

Comment: Cygwin позволяет выбрать пакеты для установки. Git bash, насколько знаю, поставляется с тем, что есть

Comment: Cygwin помимо этого содержит другие пакеты (gcc-core,gcc-g++, make, cmake, automake, wget,libiconv,openssh,nano,bash,base-cygwin,base-files,cygwin,file,gzip,login,mintty,openssl,run,tar,vim-minimal,cron,shutdown,git) если они не нужны то и нет смысла его использовать

Comment: Cygwin уже лет несколько как умер, его давно по всем параметрам превзошёл MSYS2.  Пользоваться  cygwin смысла нет.  Выбирайте или MSYS2, или WSL2 (глючная, зараза).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cygwin, безусловно, занятная вещь. Всяко лучше, чем просто git bash, хотя бы за разнообразие пакетов. Практически всё, что есть в популярных дистрибутивах линукса, было портировано для Cygwin.

Я пользовалься им много лет, регулярно страдая от косяков и трудностей с шаг-вправо-шаг-влево-побег. Это не виртуальная машина, поэтому при сборке дополнительных пакетов, которых нет в дистрибутиве, то и дело налетал на грабли. То собранные пакеты отказывались собираться, то не работали как надо.

В конечном итоге, когда в Майкрософте стали на путь примирения с Линуксом и анонсировали превью для Windows Subsystem for Linux, я с радостью снёс Cygwin и с тех пор первым делом на любом компьютере поднимаю WSL+Ubuntu.

Если вы ищете полноценный набор линуксовых утилит для виндового окружения, от всей души рекомендую WSL. Это стабильная, надёжная среда с полноценными дистрибутивами линукса, в которых работает 99.9% существующего ПО. Да, пару раз мне удавалось довести WSL до синего экрана смерти, но по сравнению с теми подводными камнями, на которые довелось напарываться в Cygwin, это такие мелочи! Главное, что в WSL полноценный линукс, со всеми компиляторами, библиотеками и системными вызовами. Я пользуюсь уже более 5 лет и очень доволен.

**UPD**

Я пользуюсь WSL-1, ибо это нашлёпка над виндоуз, как Cygwin, только лучше - более полная реализация системных вызовов, выше стабильность. Нативная работа с файловой системой Windows и сетью. WSL-2 сделали как виртуальную машину, в ней работает 100% линуксовых функций, даже докер, но я так и не освоил монтирование виндовых разделов и подключение X-сервера. Когда пробовал WSL-2, мне показалось, что с виндовыми файловыми разделами работает медленнее, чем WSL-1, поэтому разбираться не стал, остался в первой версии.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Отличный вывод получился: теперь, когда есть WSL, Cygwin больше не нужен.

Comment: @БоковГлеб да, мне wsl нравится значительно больше. нормальный дистрибутив Линукс - сила сама по себе, плюс отличная поддержка в vscode